# Is it possible to test multiple resources from a .resx file in a similar way which DataRows provide?

Tags: c#, resx, vs-unit-testing-framework

I try to test a method on multiple sources (`.eml` files) and I saved those in a `.resx` file. I tried to access those files via `DataRows` and pass them as a `TestMethod` parameter but Visual Studio spits out the following error: `An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type`. This basically means i have to hard-code all the `[DataRow()]` data. Is there any other way to access all resources and test them? My current work-around looks like this but I don't feel like that should be the only valid option on how to access all resources:

```
private static List<byte[]> _List;
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInit(TestContext tc)
{
    _List = new List<byte[]>
    {
        Resources.DisclaimerInWordSection,
        Resources.DisclaimerAboveWordSection,
        Resources.DisclaimerUnderneathWordSection
    };
}
```

This is my `TestMethod`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetDisclaimersAndIds_NoError()
{
    foreach (var bytes in _List)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(EmlInteractor.GetDisclaimersAndIds(bytes));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!